# Problems and exercises involving different subjects at the same time at the undergraduate level

Tags: soft-question, problem-solving

I know that at the research level, it's common to use different areas of Mathematics to solve a problem. But my question is whether at the undergraduate level it is possible to have a problem or exercise in which to solve it, it is necessary to use subjects that are not normally seen together. For example, a problem involving at the same time Differential Geometry and Differential Equations, or Abstract Algebra and Calculus or Linear Algebra and Combinatorics... In short, is this possible? Could someone give me examples ? PS: I'm not talking about subjects that are pre-requisite to each other like Analytic Geometry and Calculus. And remember, I'm referring to the undergraduate level.

Comment: Perhaps some problems on the Putnam exam may require use of a couple different fields

Comment: then you can have problems involving the areas I mentioned at the same time ?

Comment: Off the top of my head, linear algebra (well, systems of linear equations, at least) comes up in combinatorics solving recurrence relations. I know in an abstract algebra class we used formal differentiation to talk about, I believe, repeated roots of polynomials with variables over rings/fields other than $\mathbb{R}$. I'm sure there are at least a couple more examples in each case.